# what does axes parameter do in dot layer in keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Which values are exactly being multipled when we specify axes = (2, 2)? Can anyone tell me what really is happening behind the scenes here?

```
match = dot([input_encoded_m, question_encoded], axes=(2, 2))
match = Activation('softmax')(match)
```

Data shapes:

```
print(input_encoded_m)
print(questions_encoded)

(<tf.Tensor 'dropout_41/Identity:0' shape=(None, 552, 64) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'dropout_42/Identity:0' shape=(None, 5, 64) dtype=float32>)
```

> input_encoded_m, 552 is sentence length, 64 is embeddings length
>
> questions_encoded, 5 is sentence length, 64 is embeddings length

If we specify axes = (2, 2) in dot layer which values are being multiplied? can anyone help me with it?

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/merge/#dot_1

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I've seen the docs already but couldn't understand it. Apart from that it is taking dot product of those two tensors. But what is axes (2, 2) here. Is my embeddings are getting multiplied? is that it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axes mean the axis of your tensors.

For examples, in your case, you have a tensor of shape=(None,552,64) which is 3D(rank 3) tensor.

A scalar(e.g `3`)  is 0D tensor.

A vector (`[1,2,3]`) is 1D tensor:

A matrix ([         is 2D tensor. and so on.

```
       [1,2],
       [2,3],
        ]
```

the first axis( axis 0) is the one that has None.

The second axis( axis 1 ) is the one that has 522 rows.

The third axis ( axis 2) is the one that has 64 columns.

```
a = Input(batch_shape=(None,255,64))
b = Input(batch_shape=(None,5,64))
out = dot([a,b], axes =(2,2))
out.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(255), Dimension(5)])
```

So basically, `a.b = a1.b1 + a2.b2 +.... + a64.b64` will give one scalar.
 Since you have a row of 5, you will have a vector of 5 dimensions in the last axis of your tensor.(vector Dimension is different from tensor Dimension

Comment: so the dot product is done on embeddings i.e 64*64 . What will be the resultant shape in this case?

Comment: in theory it should be, (None, 255,5), updated my answer